# Using describe() method to exclude a column

Tags: python, dataframe, qtconsole

I am new to using python with data sets and am trying to exclude a column ("id") from being shown in the output. Wondering how to go about this using the describe() and exclude functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`describe` works on the datatypes. You can include or exclude based on the datatype & not based on columns. If your column `id` is of unique data type, then

```
df.describe(exclude=[datatype])
```

or if you just want to remove the column(s) in `describe`, then try this

```
cols = set(df.columns) - {'id'}
df1 = df[list(cols)]
df1.describe()
```

TaDa its done. For more info on `describe` click [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by slicing your original DF and remove the 'id' column. One way is through `.iloc` . Let's suppose the column 'id' is the first column from you DF, then, you could do this:

```
df.iloc[:,1:].describe()
```

The first colon represents the rows, the second the columns.

Answer (score 0):

Although somebody responded with an example given from the official docs which is more then enough, I'd just want to add this, since It might help a few ppl:

**IF** your DataFrame is large (let's say 100s columns), removing one or two, might not be a good idea (not enough), instead, create a smaller DataFrame holding what you're interested and go from there.

*Example of removing 2+ columns:*

```
    table_of_columns_you_dont_want = set(your_bigger_data_frame.colums) = {'column_1', 'column_2','column3','etc'}
your_new_smaller_data_frame = your_new_smaller_data_frame[list[table_of_columns_you_dont_want]]
your_new_smaller_data_frame.describe()
```

**IF** your DataFrame is medium/small size, you already know every column and you only need a few columns, just create a new DataFrame and then apply **describe()**:

I'll give an example from reading a .csv file and then read a smaller portion of that DataFrame which only holds what you need:

```
df = pd.read_csv('.\docs\project\file.csv')
df = [['column_1','column_2','column_3','etc']]
df.describe()
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `output.describe(exclude=['id'])`

Comment: I tried using that and it displays the message - TypeError: data type "id" not understood